# Why do Facebook links to my website give a 'can't connect' error?

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-page

My client is trying to link from her Facebook page, https://www.facebook.com/muddycreatures/ , to a site I developed, https://muddycreatures.com/ . Tapping the page link in the iOS app gives a cryptic 'can't connect - the link isn't working' error.

Tapping that same link in browsers works fine, and so does tapping 'open in Safari' from the error page.

Why does my site load everywhere except in the web view in Facebook for iOS? Has anyone seen this before?

Comment: your are open facebook url in webview?

Comment: Yes, and I see this: http://i.imgur.com/Fz4iZ0q.png

Comment: Have you found something for this problem @BenWest ?

Comment: No, and Facebook support were no help. Can't remember now what happened, maybe it disappeared with an app update. Have you run into it too? Best of luck.